# How to set the base class property of a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base class:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public string  MyProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

and then a class that gets passed a Generic class  that get passed a `TViewModel` that inherits from MyBaseClass

```
public abstract class MyGenericController<TViewModel> : Controller
    where TViewModel :  MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        object viewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TViewModel));
        viewModel.MyProperty="test";
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

This works like I want it. However as soon as I try set the base class property I get a compile error:

> object does not contain a definition for MyProperty
>   on the line

```
viewModel.MyProperty="test";
```

How do I set the property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the generic [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    TViewModel viewModel = Activator.CreateInstance<TViewModel>();
    viewModel.MyProperty="test";
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

An alternative can also be to constraint the generic type parameter (which saves you the overhead of reflection) to contain a default constructor via `TViewModel : MyBaseClass, new()`, and then:

```
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    TViewModel viewModel = new TViewModel();
    viewModel.MyProperty="test";
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Dumb mistake I had it as an object.